# Custom Dialog not showing View

Tags: android, dialog, android-layoutparams

I made a simple project if button click custom dialog appears but when I think something is missing in it?
Toast message appears when i click on button but dialog not showing and also no error occurs and app not crash.
source code

```
private void layout() {
        toast("save");

        LayoutInflater dialoglayout = LayoutInflater.from(EditImageActivity.this);
         View dialogView = dialoglayout.inflate(R.layout.save_image_dialoge,null);

         my_dialog = new Dialog(EditImageActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialog);
         my_dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
         WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
         lp.copyFrom(my_dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
         lp.width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90);
         lp.height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.90);
         my_dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
         final Button cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
         cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 //cancel(true);
                 my_dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });
     }
```

Comment: Where did you called `my_dialog.show()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to call **`my_dialog.show()`** to  display your `my_dialog`

```
private void layout() {
    toast("save");

    LayoutInflater dialoglayout = LayoutInflater.from(EditImageActivity.this);
     View dialogView = dialoglayout.inflate(R.layout.save_image_dialoge,null);

     my_dialog = new Dialog(EditImageActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialog);
     my_dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
     WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
     lp.copyFrom(my_dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
     lp.width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90);
     lp.height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.90);
     my_dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
     final Button cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
     cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             //cancel(true);
             my_dialog.dismiss();
         }
     });
     my_dialog.show();
 }
```

Comment: I accepted you answer sorry I am new in stackoverflow so don't know much, can you please read my new question and help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Call this method also

```
 my_dialog.show();
```

your method would be like this

```
private void layout() {
        toast("save");

        LayoutInflater dialoglayout = LayoutInflater.from(EditImageActivity.this);
         View dialogView = dialoglayout.inflate(R.layout.save_image_dialoge,null);

         my_dialog = new Dialog(EditImageActivity.this, R.style.CustomAlertDialog);
         my_dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
         WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
         lp.copyFrom(my_dialog.getWindow().getAttributes());
         lp.width = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels*0.90);
         lp.height = (int)(getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels*0.90);
         my_dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
         final Button cancel = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
         cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                 //cancel(true);
                 my_dialog.dismiss();
             }
         });

       my_dialog.show();
     }
```

Comment: thank you i forgot to add this. Now code is working properly

Comment: i am glad it worked, Please upvote the answer for others to use it :)